# React Hook useEffect I can't get the data

Tags: reactjs

I want to get real time bitcoin information but datas not coming. I get this error =  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'coinData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

```
 const [coinData,setCoinData] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () =>{
      const baseURL = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin?tickers=true&market_data=true&community_data=true&developer_data=true&sparkline=true"
      const response = await axios(baseURL)
      setCoinData(response);
      console.log(coinData)
    }
  getData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you're using `coinData` (state) inside `useEffect`.

If you add `coindData` to the dependencies array, you'll get an infinite loop.

To log the response use `console.log(response)`, not `console.log(coinData)`.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () =>{
      const baseURL = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin?tickers=true&market_data=true&community_data=true&developer_data=true&sparkline=true"
      const response = await axios(baseURL)
      setCoinData(response);
      console.log(response);
    }
    getData();
  }, []);
```